# How Do I Use Java Scanner Class to Track Arrow Keys Strokes

Tags: java

Why is this code not working properly? The switch case goes to default when the `Enter` key is pressed, i.e. 'invalid key pressed', while non-arrow keys do not go to the default switch case?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PathTracker{
    private int position;
    private int pathLength;

    public PathTracker(int pathLength){
        this.pathLength=pathLength;
        this.position=0;
    }

    public void front_back(char key){
        switch (key){
            case '←':
                position = (position-1 + pathLength) % pathLength;
                break;
            case '→':
                position = (position+1) % pathLength;
                break;
            case '\n':
                System.out.println("Final Position: "+position);
                System.exit(0);
                break; 
            default:
                System.out.println("invalid key pressed");
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the path length: ");
        int pathLength=scanner.nextInt();

        PathTracker tracker = new PathTracker(pathLength);

        System.out.println("Press arrow keys to move on the path. Press Enter to stop!");

        while(true){
            char key=scanner.next().charAt(0);
            tracker.front_back(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Scanner` is not designed for handling control characters. You need a GUI with key bindings

Comment: `←` and `→` are not characters generated by pressing arrow keys;  they are just visual symbols for arrow keys (and directions in general).  Arrow keys perform a system function:  They allow editing at the system level, before Scanner ever receives anything.  Console-based programs have no way to know what editing took place before the text was received from the user.  As g00se said, you have to write a GUI application to detect arrow key presses.